# Using boolean opeation between 2 arrays in python

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, and-operator

I have two arrays, lets say:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
b = np.array([1,2,10,18,3,4,7])
```

Now I would like to apply a **double condition, `2<a<6` and `2<b<6`**. Now how can I get those **objects of `a` and `b` for which `2<a<6` and `2<b<6` ?**

I tried

```
condition_a = a[(a>2)*(a<6)]
condition_b = b[(b>2)*(b<6)]

new_a = a[(condition_a) and (condition_b)]
new_b = b[(condition_a) and (condition_b)]
```

But it doesn't work!!

Comment: Theses aren't arrays, they're lists.

Comment: @asimoneau: ok let's convert them to numpy arrays.. that's not a big issue

Comment: @unutbu: Sorry!! They are of the same shapes..I made a mistake in my example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mask = (a>2) & (a<6) & (b>2) & (b<6)
new_a = a[mask]
new_b = b[mask]
```

Using `&` given the same result as `*`, but since we are performing a `logical_and` here, I think it is clearer to use `&`.